# Method not applicable for arguments

Tags: java, compiler-construction, parameters, arguments, boolean

I'm trying to create a tester class, but in doing so I have gotten an error which states:

```
1 error found:

Error: The method printData(double, double) in the type PayCalculator is not
    applicable for the arguments ()
```

How do I fix it?  This my tester code

```
PayCalculator p1 = new PayCalculator();
    p1.setHourlyRate(8.25);
    p1.setHoursWorked(45.0);    
    p1.printData();
```

my main code

```
{
  private double hourlyRate;
  private double hoursWorked;


  public PayCalculator()
  {
    hourlyRate = 0.0;
    hoursWorked = 0.0;
  }

  /**
   * Two parameter constructor
   * Add hourlyRate and hoursWorked
   * @param the hourly rate
   * @param the hours worked
   */
  public PayCalculator(double aHourlyRate, double aHoursWorked)
  {
    hourlyRate = aHourlyRate;
    hoursWorked = aHoursWorked;
  }

  /**
   * sets the hourly rate
   * @return hourlyRate
   */ 
  public void setHourlyRate(double aHourlyRate)
  {
    hourlyRate = aHourlyRate;
  }

  /**
   * gets the hourly rate
   * @param hourlyRate
   */
  public double getHourlyRate()
  {
    return hourlyRate;
  }

  /**
   * sets the hours worked
   * @return hoursWorked
   */ 
  public void setHoursWorked(double aHoursWorked)
  {
    hoursWorked = aHoursWorked;
  }

  /**
   * gets the hours worked
   * @param hours worked
   */
  public double getHoursWorked()
  {
    return hoursWorked;
  }



  public boolean workedOvertime()
  {
    if (hoursWorked > 40)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else 
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public double numHoursOvertime()
  {
    if (hoursWorked > 40)
    {
      return hoursWorked - 40;
    }
    else 
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  public double calculateGrossPay()
  {
    if (hourlyRate  <= 10.25)
    {
      if (hourlyRate <= 40)
        return hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
    }
    else 
    {  
      double grossPay = ((40 * hourlyRate) + ((hourlyRate * 2) * hoursWorked - 40));
      return grossPay;
    }

    if (hoursWorked <= 60)
    {
      return hourlyRate * hoursWorked;
    }
    else
    {
      return 60 * hourlyRate;
    }
  }

  public double determineTaxRate(double grossPay)
  {
    if (grossPay >= 800)
    {
      double tax = 0;
      tax = grossPay * 0.37;
      return tax;
    }
    else if ( grossPay >= 400)
    {
      double tax = 0;
      tax = grossPay * 0.22;
      return tax;
    }
    else
    {
      double tax = 0;
      tax = grossPay * 0.12;
      return tax;
    }
  }

  public double calculateNetPay(double grossPay, double tax)
  {
    double calculateNetPay = grossPay - tax;
    return calculateNetPay;
  }

  public void printData(double grossPay, double tax)
  {
    System.out.println("Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked);
    System.out.println("Hourly rate: " + hourlyRate);
    System.out.println("Number of hours of overtime worked: " + numHoursOvertime());
    System.out.println("Worked overtime? " + workedOvertime());
    System.out.println("Gross pay: " + calculateGrossPay());
    System.out.println("Tax Rate: " + determineTaxRate(grossPay));
    System.out.println("Net Pay: " + calculateNetPay(grossPay, tax));
  }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the `printData` function, it takes *two* arguments: `grossPay` and `tax`. However, when you call the method in your testing code, you don't give it any arguments.

Comment: Your answer to this already exists in your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286505/creating-a-tester-class-for-java). You've now posted the same question **thrice**. **Twice** from this account and **once** from your [other account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2121254/user2121254).

Answer (score 2):

Well yes. Here's the method declaration:

```
public void printData(double grossPay, double tax)
```

And here's how you're trying to call it:

```
p1.printData();
```

What values do you expect to be used for `grossPay` and `tax`?

To be honest it seems odd that you should have to pass in `grossPay` having already specified the hours worked and hourly rate, but that's a different matter. The most immediate problem is that you're not providing the arguments your method requires.

Answer (score 0):

Your method expects two values `grossPay` and `tax` :

```
public void printData(double grossPay, double tax)
```

But you are not providing  `grossPay` and `tax` to it when calling it :

```
p1.printData();
```

Include the value of  `grossPay` and `tax` when calling your method and it will work fine like :

```
p1.printData(123.00,2.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Definition of your method is:

```
public void printData(double grossPay, double tax)
```

It expects call with two double arguments whereas you are calling with no argument:

```
p1.printData();
```

Pass double arguments to `printData(44.85d, 77.56d)`