# Compilation error - Inversions counting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I am struggling in my code with an error.

This is the error I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: **Unresolved compilation problems**:
>
> The method `recur(Integer[])` in the type `D_and_con` is not applicable for the arguments (`int[]`)
>
> at edu.uqu.algorithms.inversions.D_and_con.recur(D_and_con.java:27)
>   at edu.uqu.algorithms.inversions.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:27)

The code computes the number of inversions.

It is:

```
package edu.uqu.algorithms.inversions;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import edu.uqu.algorithms.inversions.util.IOUtil;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            /*//Inversions using BRUTE FORCE
            Integer[] tokens1 = IOUtil.loadFileIntoArray("IntegerArray.txt");
            long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Started Computing Total nb of invertions BRUTE FORCE..........................");
            System.out.println("Total nb of invertions BRUTE FORCE: " + Inversions.countInvertionsBruteForce(tokens1));
            long runningTime1 = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime1);
            System.out.println("BRUTE FORCE Running time: " + runningTime1);
            System.out.println("\n");*/

            //Inversions using DIVIDE & CONQUER
            Integer[] tokens2 = IOUtil.loadFileIntoArray("IntegerArray.txt");
            long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Started Computing Total nb of invertions DIVIDE & CONQUER..........................");
            System.out.println("MMMMM" + D_and_con.recur(tokens2) );
            long runningTime2 = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2);
            System.out.println("DIVIDE & CONQUER Running time: " + runningTime2);


            System.out.println("----------------------- FINISHED -------------------------");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
----------------------------------------
/************************************
 *  
 *  The aim of this code is to count the number of inversions in 
 *  an array of integers. Two ways of counting are used, a Brute Force algorithm and 
 *  a recursive Divide and Conquer algorithm.
 *  
 ***********************************/

package edu.uqu.algorithms.inversions;

/**
public class Inversions{


/**
 * Brute force inversions counting method.
 */
public static long countInvertionsBruteForce(Integer[] entries_p)
{
    long result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < entries_p.length; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < entries_p.length; j++){
            if(entries_p[i] > entries_p[j]) result++;
        }
        //System.out.println("BRUTE FORCE intermediate result for i = " + i + " IS: " + result);
    }
    return result;
}

}
--------------------------
Divide and conquer
/************************************
 *  
 *  The aim of this code is to count the number of inversions in 
 *  an array of integers. Two ways of counting are used, a Brute Force algorithm and 
 *  a recursive Divide and Conquer algorithm.
 *  
 ***********************************/

package edu.uqu.algorithms.inversions;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class D_and_con{
    private static BigDecimal totalcount = new BigDecimal(0);
    public static Integer[] recur(Integer[] entries_p)
    {
    int n = entries_p.length;
    if(n == 1) 
    {
    return entries_p;   
    }
    int middel = n/2;
    int[] Larray = new int[middel];
    int[] Rarray = new int[n - middel];
    System.arraycopy(entries_p , 0 , Larray, 0 , Larray.length );
    System.arraycopy(entries_p , Larray.length , Rarray , 0 , Rarray.length);
    recur(Larray);\\ERROR APPEAR HERE 
    recur(Rarray);\\ERROR APPEAR HERE 
    comb(Larray , Rarray , entries_p );
    return entries_p;
    }

    private static void comb(int[] Larray, int[] Rarray, Integer[] newarray)
    {
        int LarrayL = Larray.length;
        int RarrayL = Rarray.length;
        int i=0 , j=0 , k=0 ;
        while(i< LarrayL && i<RarrayL)
            {
                if(Larray[i] < Rarray[i] )
                {
                newarray[k] = Larray[i];
                i++;
                }

                else
                {
                    newarray[k] = Rarray[j];
                    i++;
                totalcount = totalcount.add (new BigDecimal(Larray.length - 1));

                }
                k++;
            }
            while(i < LarrayL) {
            newarray[k] = Larray[i];
            i++;
            k++;
          }
          while(j < RarrayL) {
            newarray[k] = Rarray[j];
            j++;
            k++;
          }

    }
}
```

Comment: The same problem as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286774/method-not-applicable-for-arguments) old SO question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The compiler complaints that you feed your `recur` method with something of type `int[]` but you declared that it accepts `Integer[]`. Therefore take a look at the method signature

```
// entries_p is Integer[], not int[]
public static Integer[] recur(Integer[] entries_p)
```

but you feed the method with `int[]` as seen here

```
int[] Larray = new int[middel];
int[] Rarray = new int[n - middel];

...

recur(Larray);
recur(Rarray);
```

`Integer` is different to `int`. Though Java can automatically convert both into each other (**boxing**) it **won't do that** for advanced types liked arrays `Integer[]` and `int[]`.

---

### Converting

You will need to convert the types **by yourself**. Note that `Integer[]` in contrast to `int[]` is capable of storing `null`.

Here are some easy conversions, first without using Streams:

```
// from int[] to Integer[]
int[] source = ...
Integer[] target = new Integer[source.length];

for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    // Convert int to Integer
    target[i] = Integer.valueOf(source[i]);
}

// from Integer[] to int[]
Integer[] source = ...
int[] target = new int[source.length];

for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    if (source[i] == null) {
        // Don't support null values
        throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    // Convert Integer to int
    target[i] = source[i].intValue();
}
```

And now the same using `Stream`s (Java 8):

```
// from int[] to Integer[]
int[] source = ...
Integer[] target = Arrays.stream()  // IntStream
    .boxed()                        // Stream<Integer>
    .toArray(Integer[]::new)

// from Integer[] to int[]
Integer[] source = ...
int[] target = Arrays.stream()    // Stream<Integer>
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)  // Stream<Integer>
    .toArray(int[]::new)
```

---

### Changing method or argument

Instead of converting the array from one into the other type you may also adjust your method or the argument. For example you could change the method signature from

```
public static Integer[] recur(Integer[] entries_p)
```

to

```
public static Integer[] recur(int[] entries_p)
```

then it will accept `int[]` as argument. You may also change the return type to `int[]`. The other alternative would, as said, be to change the argument from `int[]` to `Integer[]`. This applies to that code section:

```
// You may change both to Integer[]
int[] Larray = new int[middel];
int[] Rarray = new int[n - middel];
```

Comment: Start by converting `Larray` and `Rarray` right before you feed them to the method. However it may be more appropriate to replace all occurrences of `Integer[]` by `int[]`. I don't see why you even used `Integer[]` in the first place. The only difference is that `Integer[]` can store `null`, do you use that? If not then you will be totally fine with `int[]` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Integer[]` arrays to `int[]` arrays!

Answer (score 0):

`"int"` is a primitive data-type and `"Integer"` is a `Class`.

To solve your problem:-

```
1 - Integer[] tokens2 = IOUtil.loadFileIntoArray("IntegerArray.txt"); //Read data from file in int[].

2 - Integer[] recur(Integer[] entries_p){} //change it as int[] recur(int[] entries_p)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , I did that and this error appeared Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method recur(int[]) in the type D_and_con is not applicable for the arguments (Integer[])

 at edu.uqu.algorithms.inversions.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:27)